# Advice how to scale Spring service that serv's Vertx handlers requests

Tags: java, spring, architecture, scale, vert.x

I am using vertx3.

As we know Vertx is very efficient handling many requests with it's reactor pattern.

The thing is that I have a second service which exposed as Rest-API on Spring-boot container(it was very easy for me to implement it over there).

I got two options: 1. Implement that logic on vertx and earn the api call.
                   2. Scale the spring-boot service to handle those millions rest api's reuqests from vertx.

Anyone had this dilema ?

will be easier to go with option two.

Any alternative how to scale the spring service ? 
(I already aware to the physical solutions of adding many instances on diff machines and put load-balancers but than I am losing the power of vertx since the spring-service is a bottleneck

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0):

Usually service implementations are stateless, regardless from technology which are you going to use. So it means, that they are scalable.

Try to implement service logic, using spring, rest-api using vertx. Spring service service logic will be used from vertx.

And of cause do not block the threads in service implementation.

Comment: What did you mean by " Spring service service logic will be used from vertx" ? the spring-service logic should be on the spring service or on the vertx? please make it clear. thank you.